# Understanding each MVVM Component

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I know there are questions similar to this one, but nothing seems to help make things click. I know in MVVM there is a Model, ViewModel, and View. I will try to make this simple so I can understand what components go inside which. In this particular code I want to be able to control the visibility of the side bar menu with the top bar menu. Then I will create a navigation for the side bar menu, but trying to figure out what goes where seems very hard and I am not sure why.

**FYI: If you are trying to recreate the namespaces were changed and I am using Material Design NuGet Package**

This should be the Base Model known as the BindableBase (I Think?) The Model contains the INotifyPropertyChanged, but because this is a base I shouldn't have any variables in this or should I?

Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MainProgram
{
    public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public string ObjectSender { get; set; }
        
        public BindableBase()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {             
                OnPropertyChanged(ObjectSender);
            });
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string sender)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(sender))); 
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };


    }
}
```

Next we have the viewModel which is where a lot of the code for the main view goes. Basically anything that will be done in the view will go in here. Usually includes ObservableCollection. I am getting confused on what goes in where and why. Also, for I am not quite sure how to go about controlling `System.Windows.Controls` from here. If you noticed towards the bottom the close function works fine, but trying to get the visibility does not really work.

View Model:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MainProgram
{
    public partial class TopMenuBarViewModel : BindableBase
    {

        #region Commands
        public ICommand Close { get; }
        public ICommand ChangeMenuVisibility { get; }
        #endregion

        public TopMenuBarViewModel()
        {
            this.Close = new RelayCommand(CloseWindow);
            this.ChangeMenuVisibility = new RelayCommand(ChangedMenuVisibility);
        }


        private void CloseWindow()
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                MainWindow mainWindow = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (mainWindow != null)
                    mainWindow.Close();

            });
            
        }

        private void ChangedMenuVisibility()
        {

            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (MainWindowViewModel.MenuVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
                    MainWindowViewModel.MenuVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                

            });
            //MainWindowViewModel.MenuVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view.cs that binds the view and the view model, but I am not sure why this is needed if I have it bound via a DataTemplate. I don't know if I am doing it twice or if they both are needed.

View:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;



namespace MainProgram
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TopMenuBar.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TopMenuBar : UserControl
    {

        public TopMenuBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var viewModel = new TopMenuBarViewModel();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XAML for the View TopMenuBar.xaml I have all my bindings correct because I see the commands are executing.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainProgram.TopMenuBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MainProgram"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button Height="auto" Width="50" Command="{Binding ChangeMenuVisibility}" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RoundCorner}" Margin="3,1">
                <Grid>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Background="Transparent" Kind="Menu" Height="auto" Width="auto"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <!--="{Binding CloseWindow}"-->
            <Button Height="auto" Width="50" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RoundCorner}" Margin="3,1">
                <Grid>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Background="Transparent" Kind="Help" Height="auto" Width="auto"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
            <Button Height="auto" Width="50" Command="{Binding Close}" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RoundCorner}" Margin="3,1">
                <Grid>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Background="Transparent" Kind="Power" Height="auto" Width="auto"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the XAML that I am trying to control the visibility for, but it doesn't let me. This is in the MainWindow.xaml. I have also seen other bits of code that allow people to bind the current view of a usercontrol, like the side bar menu, but I can't seem to get it to work no matter how hard I try.

```
 <Border Visibility="{Binding MenuVisibility}" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="5">
            <ccontrols:DeitoContentControl  x:Name="MenuSectionView"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModellocal:NavigationMenuViewModel}">
                        <Viewlocal:NavigationMenu/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
               
            </ccontrols:DeitoContentControl> 
        </Border>
```

This is the MainWindowViewModel that has the binding variable in it. `ViewModelBase` derives from BindableBase.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MainProgram
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Private Members

        private UserControl _currentFrame;

        private static Visibility _MenuVisibility;
        #endregion



        #region Constructors

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
           
        }

        public UserControl CurrentFrame
        {
            get { return _currentFrame; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _currentFrame)
                    return;
                _currentFrame = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentFrame");
            }
        }

        public static Visibility MenuVisibility
        {
            get { return _MenuVisibility; }
            set
            {
                if (_MenuVisibility == value)
                    return;
                _MenuVisibility = value;
                //OnPropertyChanged("MenuVisibility");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (s, e) => { };

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string sender)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(sender)));
        }

      
        #endregion



    }
}
```

Thank you for reading and stopping by to help out. If there is something I need to change, add, edit just let me know. I didn't show the code for the full MainWindow, but I can if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, I'm no expert on MVVM, but I have worked with it in the past, so let me try to clarify some things. To anyone more knowledgeable: please feel free to correct me.

---

> This should be the Base Model known as the BindableBase (I Think?) The Model contains the INotifyPropertyChanged, [...]

Since you didn't post the `ViewModelBase` source I'm going assume it just inherits from `BindableBase` and doesn't add anything else. In that case the only reason for the separation I could think of is to allow models to inherit from `BindableBase`.
This is not part of the code idea behind MVVM, models are expected to be completely separate from any ui logic and therefore usually do **not** implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
(As an aside, it is of course possible to have models implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but as you're trying to understand the core MVVM concepts I think this just adds confusion).

As explained [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_introduction.htm), the **model** itself does not contain any logic related to interaction with the UI, but just the data and logic required for the underlying tasks your application is trying to solve.
I usually think of it this way:

> **If I want to have both a command line version and a UI app, which parts would I move to a library that can be included by both versions?**

The answer to that is most likely what should be in your models.

If the application's sole purpose is to experiment with the WPF bindings, it doesn't need any such logic and therefore won't have any models.

---

Let's take a more detailed look at your `BindableBase` class. My first advice would be to merge it with the `ViewModelBase` class and have all view models inherit from it.
Its purpose is to handle everything around the `PropertyChanged` event so you don't have to include that code in every view model, and it should indeed not contain any fields or properties apart from the `PropertyChanged` event.

The `OnPropertyChanged` method is supposed to receive the *name of the changed property* and call the `PropertyChanged` event handler. Note that your implementation erroneously always passes the string `"sender"` as the property name due to the `nameof` operator. **This is most likely why your visibility change events are never received.**

The name `sender` is also usually used to refer to the *object firing an event* (note how the first parameter of the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` delegate is called `sender` and you're passing `this`).

In addition you might want to look at [the `CallerMemberName` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-5.0), with it you don't always have to manually specify the property name.

Apart from that I'm a bit confused what the purpose of the `ObjectSender` property and your constructor is. If I'm not missing anything, `ObjectSender` will likely be `null` when the `Task` in the constructor is run and the `PropertyChanged` event won't have any subscribers, so nobody is going to act on that fired event anyway.

Applying all of these points, we end up with something like this:

```cs
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
    }
}
```

---

Next is the `TopMenuBarViewModel`. It looks mostly fine to me, apart from the fact that it inherits from `BindableBase` instead of `ViewModelBase` and I don't see a reason to have a view model `partial`.

The naming convention I've usually seen implemented is to end all `ICommand` properties with the word `Command`, that way you don't run into name conflicts with the implementing method.

I also don't understand why `MainWindowViewModel.Visibility` is supposed to be `static`, did you maybe not figure out how else to access it?

`TopMenuBarViewModel` with proposed changes:

```cs
public class TopMenuBarViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Commands

    public ICommand CloseWindowCommand { get; }
    public ICommand ChangeMenuVisibilityCommand { get; }
    
    #endregion
    
    public TopMenuBarViewModel()
    {
        this.CloseWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(CloseWindow);
        this.ChangeMenuVisibilityCommand = new RelayCommand(ChangeMenuVisibility);
    }
    
    private void CloseWindow()
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows
                .OfType<MainWindow>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (mainWindow != null)
                mainWindow.Close();
        });
    }

    private void ChangeMenuVisibility()
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            // You might want to consider querying the MainWindowViewModel once
            // in the constructor and storing it for future use.
            MainWindow mainWindow = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows
                .OfType<MainWindow>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if(!(mainWindow.DataContext is MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel))
                return; // invalid view model

            switch(mainWindowViewModel.MenuVisibility)
            {
                case Collapsed:
                case Hidden:
                    mainWindowViewModel.MenuVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
                case Visible:
                    mainWindowViewModel.MenuVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

You mention that you're setting the `TopMenuBar`'s `DataContext` twice, once in the constructor and once with a `DataTemplate`. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "bound via `DataTemplate`", that code seems to be missing. Do you mean something like this?

```xml
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myviewmodels:TopMenuBarViewModel}">
            <myviews:TopMenuBar/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    <myviewmodels:TopMenuBarViewModel/>
</ContentControl>
```

If yes, it could probably be simplified to something this (it's been a while, so it might not be entirely correct):

```xml
<myviews:TopMenuBar>
    <myviews:TopMenuBar.DataContext>
        <myviewmodels:TopMenuBarViewModel/>
    </myviews:TopMenuBar.DataContext>
</myviews:TopMenuBar>
```

Either way, the XAML-bound `DataContext` should take precedence, so setting it in the constructor is unnecessary unless you want a "fallback" instance in case it is not set explicitly.

Apart from that, I don't have much to say much about the XAML code. The bindings all look correct to me (command names need to be adjusted if you end up changing them as proposed above).

In case you don't already know about this: you can add the attribute
`d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=myviewmodels:TopMenuBarViewModel}"`
to your `UserControl` start tag, that will give you IntelliSense auto completion for data bindings.

---

Lastly, your `MainWindowViewModel`. The whole point of the `ViewModelBase` base class is that your concrete view models **don't** have to deal with implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` (it is already implemented in the base class).
That means the bottom part of your implementation is not needed.

As mentioned above, I don't see a reason why `MenuVisibility` is supposed to be `static`.

Also, note how I removed the explicit string parameters to `OnPropertyChanged`. This is made possible by the `CallerMemberName` attribute mentioned above. You could also use `nameof(CurrentFrame)`, but please *never* just manually write it as a string literal. That will break as soon as you decide to rename one of the properties and is prone to typos.

`MainWindowViewModel` with proposed changes:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase,
{
    private UserControl _currentFrame;
    public UserControl CurrentFrame
    {
        get => _currentFrame;
        set
        {
            if (value == _currentFrame)
                return;
            _currentFrame = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Visibility _menuVisibility;
    public Visibility MenuVisibility
    {
        get => _menuVisibility;
        set
        {
            if (value == _menuVisibility)
                return;
            _menuVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Wow, this turned into much more of a code review than I originally intended, but I hope there is still some useful information for you in there.

All code in this answer was written from memory, so please excuse any errors I might have made.